# How to use HTTP2 behind AWS Network Load Balancer terminating SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, http2

I have the following setup:

```
client --> AWS NLB (terminates SSL) --> nginx --> webserver
```

How can I get nginx to serve content over HTTP2? Enabling it on the nginx server config just causes the browser to download a file when accessing a page.

Comment: Any success in solving this setup?

Comment: @TončiD. Check out the setup and advice in my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594080/102443.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid an extra ALB layer, but that seems to be impossible at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I ultimately arrived at was this:

```
client --> AWS NLB --> AWS ALB (terminates SSL) --> nginx --> webserver
```

The trick was to use TCP on port 443 on the NLB **at creation time**! The web ui *does not* permit you to add a TCP listener on 443 afterward — it requires you to use the TLS choice on 443 and select a cert for TLS termination. The only reason I'm using NLB is because it supports static IP association. TCP passthrough to the ALB works for my use case.

Since the ALB terminates TLS and also supports HTTP/2 this setup works.

Comment: what's the point of the NLB in front of an ALB?  why not go direct to the ALB?

Comment: @StephenBlum NLB can be assigned a fixed IP address. Goal was to point domain apex (non route53) at it, therefore ALB w/ CNAME wouldn't work for this setup.

Comment: Hi @cachance7 does the ALB support HTTP/2 to upstreams like Nginx?  Or just HTTP/1.1 ?  Our team uses gRPC and we need end-to-end HTTP/2.

Comment: @StephenBlum I don't see anything in the documentation or configuration screens to indicate that ALB supports HTTP/2 to upstreams (though if you try it and it works then do let me know!) I think your options are to rely on transport layer load balancing or use the nginx module specifically created to handle gRPC.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers use ALPN as part of the TLS negotiation to decide to sue the HTTP/2 protocol.

As your TLS termination is happening at the NLB it must announce this HTTP/2 support and the pass on the unencrypted HTTP/2 data to Nginx.

I can’t see anything to suggest that NLB supports setting of ALPN so not sure this is possible. You will need to ask AWS if this is supported as nothing in their documentation on it, but that in itself probably gives you the answer that you don’t want.

Not sure why it’s downloading a file. Does the same thing happen if you connect directly to Nginx?

Comment: NLB now supports alpn: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/network-load-balancer-now-supports-tls-alpn-policies/